# XLOOKUP with multiple criteria and date between two dates

Tags: excel

I have a question about the XLOOKUP function in Excel. I am self-employed and I am trying to improve my tool that I use to write my invoices. For this I have an Excel file with two worksheets. One worksheet is my timesheet in which I enter the client, the date, the activity and the time spent. In the other worksheet I manage my invoices. Here I enter in particular the invoice number, the client and the billing period.

I've been trying for some time to write a function that automatically finds the corresponding invoice number for each entry in the timesheet, if the entry can be assigned to an invoice. For this I need a LOOKUP function that returns the invoice number if the following criteria are met:

An invoice exists for the client AND the date of the respective timesheet entry is within the billing period of the invoice.

I tried this: https://exceljet.net/formula/xlookup-with-logical-criteria and put together this formula for myself:

```
=XLOOKUP(1;(Table4[Clients]=[@Client])*([@Date]>=Table4[Billed Period (Start)])*([@Date]<=Table4[Billed Period (End)]); Table4[Invoice Number])
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work :/

I think it may be because I am working with tables? However, this is very important for me, because without tables my automatic invoice generation in Word will stop working. Could someone help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: what does `Unfortunately that doesn't work :/` entail.  Please add what the error you are getting.

Comment: Tables shouldn't prevent formulas from working. Please post the layouts of your tables.